# .NET Core 2.1 SDK Linux x64 No usable version of the libssl was found

Tags: .net-core

I have downloaded the dotnet-core binary SDK packet (dotnet-sdk-2.1.400-linux-x64.tar.gz) and want to install it on my void-linux system which uses LibreSSL. After i run `dotnet help` i got the response `No usable version of the libssl was found` and the execution gets aborted.

Would it be possible to get the SDK running with LibreSSL or what version of the libssl is needed? I couldn't figure out to what ssl-library dotnet is linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibreSSL [is not supported at all by .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26739).

.NET Core needs to use OpenSSL version 1.0. It does not even support OpenSSL 1.1 (which is API and ABI incompatible with OpenSSL 1.0).
**Edit 2021**: Recent versions of .NET Core and .NET >= 5 support OpenSSL 1.1 now. Support for OpenSSL 3.0 is planned too.

.NET Core is actually looking (via `dlopen`) for lots of permutations of files that would match paths like `/usr/lib(64)/libssl.so.*`.

Comment: Thanks for that link.
As described a `CLR_OPENSSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=45 dotnet run` would work but without any support.